# SCCM 2012 Installation Error - Download() failed with 0x80072EE2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, wsus, sccm

I have been looking into SCCM for sometime now for mass imaging and group policy/software updates and installation so I decided to set it up in a virtual environment and start using it. Everything has gone fine so far up until the actual installation of SCCM 2012 and it is pulling an error when trying to download the prereq files. I have two virtual servers setup both with Windows Server 2012, one setup as a Domain Controller with a similar active directory setup to my office one, and the other with SQL, IIS, Windows Update Services, and hopefully soon SCCM. This is all configured on Virtualbox. The domain controller has one virtual internal subnet running off a Windows DHCP server.

Here are the last few lines of the installation log files:

```
    INFO: Extracted file C:\PreFiles\LanguagePack\Server\DEU\smssetup\OSD\Tools\WTG\Creator\de-de\wtgcreator.exe.mui  $$<Configuration Manager Setup><06-07-2015 22:08:36.431+420><thread=3116 (0xC2C)>
    INFO: Downloading http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=525261 as Server_ESN.cab  $$<Configuration Manager Setup><06-07-2015 22:08:36.431+420><thread=3116 (0xC2C)>
    INFO: checking if there's an explicit proxy server.  $$<Configuration Manager Setup><06-07-2015 22:08:36.431+420><thread=3116 (0xC2C)>
    INFO: WinHttpQueryHeaders() in Download() returned OK  $$<Configuration Manager Setup><06-07-2015 22:08:36.994+420><thread=3116 (0xC2C)>
    ERROR: Download() failed with 0x80072EE2  $$<Configuration Manager Setup><06-07-2015 22:10:06.401+420><thread=3116 (0xC2C)>
```

I apologize for how basic this question is but I'm a little stuck. I've found a few posts online with this error but usually they are not related to the actual setup of the software. I have tried to manually download the prereq files but it pulls the same error. Maybe I missed installing an important role or feature?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated! I'm very excited at learning more about SCCM.

Comment: It would appear the problem was the Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Features for anyone else having this problem. You can change this option to off in Server Manager.

Comment: Can you **elaborate the solution** and put it in answer box below. It would be great solution for future visitors with similar problem :)